# In STM32F101 controller, I2C BUSY flag is set due to communication interrupted due to reset. Recovery mechanism is also failing

Tags: c, embedded, stm32, i2c

In STM32F101 with some mishap with the reset, BUSY flag is held high. To come out of it, I followed the steps given in page 26 of following document from STM :

https://www.st.com/content/ccc/resource/technical/document/errata_sheet/7d/02/75/64/17/fc/4d/fd/CD00190234.pdf/files/CD00190234.pdf/jcr:content/translations/en.CD00190234.pdf

While doing the steps,I could able to do the 1st step. In the second step (Set SCL and SDA as open drain output with their values high) , I have set both SCL and SDA as output open drain, but could if I set the pins high, only SCL's IDR register is set high and SDA pin's IDR register could not be set (but it's ODR register is set). Because of this I could not able to continue with further steps. Please help me through this

Answer (score 2):

This not the issue in this case. The slave device is keeping the SDA low. To exit from this deadlock you need to provide between 8 and 12 clocks. You need to toggle the SCL pin, and after every clock you need to check if the SDA line has been released by the slave device. This has nothing in common with this errata.

After this is good to reset the I2C peripheral.

Comment: So this errata has nothing to do with slave holding the bus ? I also tried by giving clock pulses, in such a way of giving clock pulse and recovering we must check SDA's state right ? In that case the SDA should be made as GPIO input or GPIO output ?? I tried it with output, the bus got recovered, but in the next cycle the same slave which was very well communicating sends an NACK for the address (there is always a spike in the 9th clock). I dont know whether am doing any wrong in handling the GPIO which causes such a spike. help me through it if possible

Comment: When you interrupt the transmission (by reset for example) when the slave is sending data and it is waiting for the clocks - then the micro (master) is not guilty.

Comment: Ya I got your point. I am having one more query. If we are going to generate clock and see whether the SDA is up or not, then why should we convert SDA from AF to GPIO ? Cant we read the status of GPIO in AF mode itself with just SCL being converted to GPIO Output ?? If we should convert SDA to be GPIO also, then should it be configured as input or output ? (with pullup / open drain config ? ) what is the reason for it. Please enlight me

Comment: Because I2C is off and we need to check the state of the GPIO. This is the correct  way. When you read the state of the GPIO is has to be input.